# Is there a bitcount operation in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I try to write a simple hamming distance function in pytorch:

```
xorimg = torch.bitwise_xor(img1,img2)
for i in range(bitlen) : 
        hdist = hdist + (xorimg & 1)
        xorimg = xorimg >> 1
```

I wonder if there is a simple bitcount operation to count the 1s bits to get rid of the for loop

such as:

```
xorimg = torch.bitwise_xor(img1,img2)
hdist = torch.bitcount(xorimg)
```

or any other equivalent way to get rid of time consuming for-loop?

or pytorch support hamming distance directly such as:

```
hdist = torch.hamming(img1,img2)
```

that would be even better.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see answer [here](https://davidstutz.de/implementing-custom-pytorch-tensor-operations-in-c-and-cuda/)

if want to use cuda intrinsic function __popc() in cupy part, then replace the following while loop (bitcount):

```
while(x != 0){
  x = x & (x - 1);
  dist[elem_idx]++;
}
```

with cuda instrinsic function for int32:

```
dist[elem_idx] = __popc(x);
```

or with a little bit modification in both torch.py and cupy.py for int64:

```
dist[elem_idx] = __popcll(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting a second answer because I had some time to think about the question and I realized you can probably very easily provide a native implementation yourself, even if PyTorch doesn't.

This is the source code in C:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>

void bitcount(unsigned long long *buf, size_t len) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    buf[i] = __builtin_popcountll(buf[i]);
  }
}
```

Compile with:

```bash
cc -O3 -march=nehalem bitcount.c -fPIC -shared -o bitcount.so
```

(Note the Intel Nehalem CPU architecture, released in 2008, was the first to support the POPCNT instruction.)

I tested performance on an array with 10 million random 64-bit integers:

```py
import numpy as np

def Bitcount1(a):
  counts = a & 1
  for i in range(1, 64):
    counts += (a >> i) & 1
  return counts

# More efficient versions from Wikipedia
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight

m1  = 0x5555555555555555
m2  = 0x3333333333333333
m4  = 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f
m8  = 0x00ff00ff00ff00ff
m16 = 0x0000ffff0000ffff
m32 = 0x00000000ffffffff
h01 = 0x0101010101010101

def Bitcount2(a):
  a = (a & m1 ) + ((a >>  1) & m1 )
  a = (a & m2 ) + ((a >>  2) & m2 )
  a = (a & m4 ) + ((a >>  4) & m4 )
  a = (a & m8 ) + ((a >>  8) & m8 )
  a = (a & m16) + ((a >> 16) & m16)
  a = (a & m32) + ((a >> 32) & m32)
  return a

def Bitcount3(a):
  a = a - ((a >> 1) & m1)
  a = (a & m2) + ((a >> 2) & m2)
  a = (a + (a >> 4)) & m4
  return (a * h01) >> 56


# Native solution via ctypes
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./bitcount.so')
lib.bitcount.restype = None
lib.bitcount.argtypes = (np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.ulonglong, flags=('ALIGNED', 'CONTIGUOUS', 'WRITEABLE')), ctypes.c_size_t)

def Bitcount4(a):
  a = np.copy(a, order='C')
  lib.bitcount(a, a.size)
  return a


#
# Test code follows
#

def GenTestArray(n):
  return np.random.default_rng().integers(0, 2**64, n, dtype=np.uint64)

a=GenTestArray(10_000_000)
r1 = Bitcount1(a)
r2 = Bitcount2(a)
r3 = Bitcount3(a)
r4 = Bitcount4(a)

assert (r1 == r2).all()
assert (r1 == r3).all()
assert (r1 == r4).all()

from timeit import timeit

print(timeit('Bitcount1(a)', globals=globals(), number=1))
print(timeit('Bitcount2(a)', globals=globals(), number=1))
print(timeit('Bitcount3(a)', globals=globals(), number=1))
print(timeit('Bitcount4(a)', globals=globals(), number=1))
```

The results are as follows (execution times in seconds):

```
2.3275568269891664    # Bitcount1()
0.31765274197096005   # Bitcount2()
0.16485577001003549   # Bitcount3()
0.023819021007511765  # Bitcount4()
```

These timings will vary a little between runs and depending on the machine, of course, but I think the overall picture is pretty clear: while Bitcount2() is ~8 times faster than Bitcount1() (close to what I predicted), and Bitcount3() is nearly twice as fast again, the native solution blows all others out of the water: it's almost 100 times faster than the original approach, and still 7 times faster than the next-best solution.

So if you want to do bitcounting really, really fast, you will have to load a native library to do it.

Caveat: the above solution uses numpy arrays and you asked about PyTorch. But you can probably use the same approach, since Tensors and numpy arrays are very similar and you often can convert between them cheaply. See: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/basics#numpy_compatibility

Comment: This is a very nice benchmark. Question: can we port this Bitcount4 into cuda for pytorch lib to enjoy the tensor parallelism on matrix operation?

Comment: @paul: fair question. Calculating the bitcount with CUDA should be possible, but it's a little too advanced for me: I know little about PyTorch and CUDA, and I don't have a CUDA-capable device to test on.

Some pointers on how it might be possible: CUDA has a bitcount intrinsic (see __popcll() at https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT.html) and PyTorch supports CUDA extensions written in C++ (see https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html). It should be possible to put the two together, but I don't think I'll be able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you a definite answer on whether this can be done natively with PyTorch (though some quick Googling suggests no), but if you want to speed up your loop, counting bits is a well-known problem which has reasonable standard solutions. A few algorithms are listed here: [https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel) and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight

The function labeled `popcount64a()` on Wikipedia should be easy to port to Python and counts bits of 64-bit integers in 24 operations, which would be 8 times faster than your current version which does 192 operations if bitlen=64.